Локальный хост без открытия портов и статического IP через VPS-сервер как посредник
У меня есть хороший компьютер, который я хочу использовать в качестве хоста, но мой провайдер не предоставляет возможности открывать порты и получать статический IP.
Можно ли купить VPS-сервер со статическим IP-адресом и через него хостить что-либо? Например, я запущу сайт на 443 порту своего пк и захочу на него зайти извне локальной сети по <адрес_vps_сервера>:443
Если это можно сделать, то какой наиболее простой и эффективный способ это сделать?

Без статического ip от вашего провайдера, доступ извне к вашему пк вы не получите

@SwaD да прям таки. Различные сервисы типа ngrok этим и занимаются. И self-hosted решений по типу ngrok тоже хватает. В крайнем случае vpn при должном умении не только в одну сторону умеет работать

Можно, только от создаваемых таким способом задержек может быть немножко грустно
